# Data Binding between 2 XAML files

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I am creating a WP8 app using C#.

I have 2 XAML files representing 2 pages : `MainPage` and `InfoPage`

I want a header title for both of the page to be the same.

So the header title for `MainPage` is set to "MyApp"

Now, is it possible to bind the header title for `InfoPage` to the one in `MainPage`? So that both XAML has "MyApp" as the header title.

If this is not possible, why?

Thanks

Comment: It's possible. Use `Locator` as your data context on that particular element on both pages.

Comment: I found a solution. I added a string for the title name in `AppResources.resx` using the designer. Then I bind the `TextBlock` to it via `LocalizedStrings.cs`. I tried binding straight to `AppResources.resx` by adding datacontext in `XAML` but this gives me `XamlParseException` error. No idea why...

Comment: @LokmanLuke I've added a solution, which shows how to use variables from AppResources.resx.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek How do I use the `Locator` for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment to use LocalizedResources via xaml you have add Binding Path and show which class to use, for example this will work
In App.xaml add key which points to your class LocalizedStrings:

```
<Application.Resources xmlns:my="clr-namespace:NameSpaceWhereLocalizedStrings">
    <my:LocalizedStrings x:Key="Localized"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

clr-namespace: - is a namespace where you have your LocalizedStrings (probably your main namespace). Then you can use in any other xaml file your LocalizedResources:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding LocalizedResources.appName, Source={StaticResource Localized}}"/>
```

appName - is your variable in AppResources.resx (of course check if it's public). LocalizedResources is a class which you probably have as a default in LocalizedStrings.cs:

```
public class LocalizedStrings
{
  private static AppResources _localizedResources = new AppResources();
  public AppResources LocalizedResources { get { return _localizedResources; } }
}
```

Localized Resources are very usefull, because with them you can localize your App, so that users can have your Resources in different languages [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637520%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). There are also much more blogs and sites where you can find more.

Comment: @LokmanLuke If there is a solution that solved your problem, don't forget to mark it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes create a helper class that stores the variable and triggers a property change event. Then create a static object of the helper class in either main or infopage.

So to call the binding property.

```
public class BindHelper: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void PropertyChanged(string info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }


        string _title; 
        public string Title
        {
            get 
            {
                return _title; 
            }
            set
            {
                _title= value;
                PropertyChanged("Title");
            }
         }
}
```

Then in main declare an object, very simple example.

```
public static BindHelper binder = new BindHelper();
binder.Title = "My Title";
```

Change from the info page:

```
MainWindow.binder.Title = "Something Else";
```

Then just do the same binding property and datacontext settings in both. 
For infopage just set the:

```
control.DataContext = MainWindow.binder;
```

Comment: I missed it was for WP8, not sure that it applies there.  I will delete if not relevant.

Comment: This is a useful technique. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this via making style in App.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="PageHeaderTitleTextBlock" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="My App" />

    </Style>
```

and set the style in both pages

Comment: Good idea. Very helpful indeed

Comment: As you can see I only have 1 reputation :(